# How to get org-mode to generate code multiple times in one file without redundancy?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

(Follow-up to [Is there a way to use org-mode to render generated code?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/20500/6761))

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :exports results :results output :wrap SRC haskell
sed '/^elts/,$p' -n Heap03.hs
#+END_SRC
```

lets me extract Haskell code from a file to show in org-mode's export. It's effectively a safer and more idiomatic version of the hack I came up with:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :exports results :results output verbatim raw
echo '#+BEGIN_SRC haskell'
sed '/^elts/,$p' -n Heap03.hs
echo '#+END_SRC'
#+END_SRC
```

Now I want more abstraction. For example:

```
#+NAME: inline
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :exports none :results output verbatim raw
echo '#+BEGIN_SRC haskell'
echo "[[./$FILE][$FILE]]"
sed '/^elts/,$p' -n $FILE
echo '#+END_SRC'
#+END_SRC

#+CALL: inline(FILE="Heap01.hs")
#+CALL: inline(FILE="Heap02.hs")
```

The two criteria I'm trying to satisfy (and having trouble) are:

1. I should have a link to the file automatically inserted above the Haskell code.
2. The call should be as minimal as possible.

I haven't figured out how to get the first criterion satisfied using `:wrap`, and the best I can do toward the second criterion is `#+CALL: inline(FILE="Heap01.hs") :wrap SRC haskell`, which is just a bit too heavyweight for my taste.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about (note : after name, and the :var definition):

```
#+name: inline
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :exports none :results output verbatim raw :var FILE=""
echo "[[./$FILE][$FILE]]"
echo '#+BEGIN_SRC haskell'
sed '/^elts/,$p' -n $FILE
cat $FILE
echo '\n#+END_SRC'
#+END_SRC
```

And then (with results raw):

```
#+CALL: inline(FILE="Heap01.hs") :results raw
```

Comment: (The lack of a colon was just a transcription error on my part) This will break if the Haskell file contains "#+END_SRC" in the section being extracted, right?

I tried to write an `org-mode` function that calls an `org-mode` function, but I couldn't get that to work. I'm wondering if I should just throw some elisp at the problem.

Comment: you would want to escape the #+END_SRC as ,#+END_SRC. Also escape any lines beginning with * as ,*.

It seems you are going the opposite way of tangling. Why not put your haskell code in org, and use tangle to get out, rather than the opposite?

Comment: No good reason. Partially, I'm exploring `org-mode`'s functionality; partially, my first instinct was to make a bunch of similar Haskell files to demonstrate a progression, but only display parts of them inline, and I'm just following it.